# Android layout not loaded on onStart()

Tags: android, layout, load, oncreate, onstart

While showing a background I want to run some operations (without using threads).

In my activity on `onCreate()` I have `setContentView(R.layout.splash);`

When the app fires `onStart()`, the layout is not loaded yet. Why?

**UPDATE**: LogCat gives me "Activity has leaked window"

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**onCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

}
```

**onStart**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    if (CBConstants.ASSETS_MANAGER){

        String progressMsg = this.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_dialog_assets_upgrading_message);
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, progressMsg);

        progressDialog.show();

        try {

                            [...]

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("appcheck", ""+e);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, CBWebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    }


    else {
        Thread noAssetManager = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (splashActive && ms < splashTime) {
                    if(!paused)
                        ms=ms+100;
                    sleep(100);
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                if (LOG) Log.d("appcheck", ""+e);
            }
            finally {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, CBWebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        };
        noAssetManager.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: if some errors in logcat please post them, and post your code, or the relevant part of Your code. Even layout xml, please

Comment: Is the app throwing any exception?

Comment: Maybe your activity does not register in Manifest file?

Comment: update: LogCat gives me "Activity has leaked window"

Comment: there could be different reasons. How big is Your "splash" image (size in px and and storage size). It would be helpful if You post the complete logcat output, because "Has leaked Window" is often just an error caused of another error.....